# Testing Polling with React Hooks Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have created a custom Hook called usePolling which accepts a function to poll over a period of time (declared by interval) the hook works fine but now I am trying to test it... i am gettting the Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...). error and I have taken a look at Kent's videos about testing async hooks however i am struggling to get the warning to go away... the test passes however.

The line jest is complainig about is

```rb
} finally {
    > 67 |       setBusy(false);
         |       ^
      68 |     }
```

Which makes sense as that is a state change... however you will see that my test has wrapped everything in act

Here is a GIST i made > https://gist.github.com/FrancisLeigh/f62bb3c68d16e434019d4843c86e6cf6

Thank you in advance :slight_smile:

Comment: You'll want to change your test so that it awaits until the current.busy value is set back to false after the request has triggered.

Comment: @Win are you able to give me some more insight into this? I've tried using `waitForValueToChange` but not playing nicely atm.

Comment: Hi Francis, I've attached the answer, sorry for the late reply as life hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the hook more reliable when it comes to testing by accepting an `axiosOverride` prop which I can then obviously control & assert much easier.

For anyone interest > https://gist.github.com/FrancisLeigh/f62bb3c68d16e434019d4843c86e6cf6

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late reply but I have only managed to check your answer and I find the above solution a little hacky by enforcing a creation of a prop to override axios so I've detailed a possible solution to your problem below. I've not based this off the git link you posted below as there was a look of bulk that could cause confusion.

It's very important that we use await waitFor to ensure that we can listen for the the updates made to busy BEFORE and AFTER the promise is invoked so that it does not trigger the `Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)` warning.

I think the message is a little deceiving to users because users normally think wrapping said issue in an act will resolve the issue but in this case, the problem actually lies within the use of setInterval and it being able to update the state.

Hopefully, you find my solution helpful and work towards deprecating the `axiosOverrideProp`.

#### usePollingHook.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import requestAdaptor from './requestAdaptor';

export function usePollingHook(pollTimeMs = 2000) {
    const [busy, setBusy] = React.useState(false);
    const [isPolling, setPolling] = React.useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isPolling) {
            const poll = async () => {
                if (!busy) {
                    setBusy(true);
                    const resp = await requestAdaptor();
                    setBusy(false);
                    setData(resp);
                }
            };
            const interval = setInterval(poll, pollTimeMs);
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }

        return () => null;
    }, [isPolling, busy, setBusy, pollTimeMs]);

    return {
        data,
        busy,
        isPolling,
        setPolling,
    };
}
```

#### index.spec.js

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { usePollingHook } from './usePollingHook';
import requestAdaptor from './requestAdaptor';

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.mock('./requestAdaptor', () => jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(1));

describe('usePollingHook', () => {
    it('returns default props', () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => usePollingHook());

        expect(result.current.data).toEqual(null);
        expect(result.current.busy).toEqual(false);
        expect(result.current.isPolling).toEqual(false);
        expect(result.current.setPolling).toEqual(expect.any(Function));
    });

    it('ensures the state is updated when the hook has polled a request', async (done) => {
        const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => usePollingHook());

        expect(result.current.busy).toEqual(false);

        act(() => {
            result.current.setPolling(true);
        });

        await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isPolling).toEqual(true));

        act(() => {
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000);
        });

        await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.busy).toEqual(true));
        expect(requestAdaptor).toBeCalled();
        await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.busy).toEqual(false));
        expect(result.current.data).toEqual(1);
        done();
    });
});
```

#### requestAdaptor.js

Some fake http function that would wrap around a promise e.g. to simulate axios or fetch

```
export function requestAdaptor() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        return setTimeout(() => {
            return resolve({ userId: 1 });
        }, 1000);
    });
}

export default requestAdaptor;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your follow up :-) 

I managed to get around my issue by mocking my hook altogether as asynchronous-state-updates caused Jest to bug out, so better to just mock the methods returned from my useAxios hook. 

Thank you for your work :-)